# Would [cantor-theorem] be a constructive tag?

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-management

> Would [cantor-theorem] be a constructive tag?

A [search for question's containing the keywords](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=cantor%27s+theorem+is%3Aq) yields $427$ results. Feel free to comment to discuss below or just upvote/downvote.

Note:

> The [theorem I am referencing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_theorem) is the following:
>
> > For every set $A$, $|A|<|\mathcal P(A)|$

Comment: Which theorem of his?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor's_theorem

Comment: There is also [Cantor's intersection theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_intersection_theorem).

Comment: For every set $A$, $|A|<|\mathcal P(A)|$

Comment: Also there is the diagonal argument, which is an extension of Cantor's theorem, but named differently.

Comment: I'd guess that searching for [cantor's theorem is:q](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=cantor%27s+theorem+is%3Aq) may include many questions related to other results. (If you try to sort the results by *[active](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=cantor%27s%20theorem%20is%3aq)* rather than by *[relevance](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=cantor%27s%20theorem%20is%3aq)*, you will very likely find a few questions which are definitely not about this topic.)

Comment: To get a more realistic estimate, I would either try to [add elementary-set-theory tag](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Belementary-set-theory%5D+cantor%27s+theorem+is%3Aq) or search for ["cantor's theorem" is:q](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22cantor%27s+theorem%22+is%3Aq) and perhaps also ["cantor theorem" is:q](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22cantor+theorem%22+is%3Aq). (The last seem to return also questions about Heine-Cantor theorem.) Having said that, number of questions is not the only factor to be considered when discussing creation a new tag.

Comment: I voted to reopen your recent answer to [this meta post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28259/three-levels-of-math). It seems to me that StackExchange's explicit disinterest is quite relevant!